# Jmeter strategy to test 10000 users visiting a link and points to be in noted in report

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

On my local machine I need to test performance of one particular link (with static data) lets say homepage.

What I have tried:

1. 1000 users
2. Ramp up time - 600s (10 mins)
3. Loop count - 10

This makes till 10,000th user in 10th min.

**But I want its performance when 10k users hitting it together, how to plan it?** The way I tried is 10k users in 2 sec with loop count of 10. But that slowed the Jmeter. Rampup time 2 secs because I am assuming user would 2 sec atleast to think and then click.

I am running it in in NON GUI mode, without any listener, and creating a .csv file.
**Which all components are matter of concern and how to put them infront of DEV to fix them as bug or improvement?**
Local Machine config. : 8GB RAM, 64 bit Windows 7 Pro, 2.2GHz 4 CPUs

I referred to this particular link: http://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/jmeter_performance_tuning_tips/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad, any answers would be likely to be based on opinions, and the question may be better on sqa.stackexchange.com .

Comment: "too" broad? how many solutions you can think of for this problem?

Comment: YOu ask *"how to plan it"* that suggests that you can think of many ways and want guidance on them. You also ask for guidance on how to report issues to the development team. I suggested two reason why the question is off topic and I suggested a better place to ask. Please read the [help/on-topic] about what is on topic here.

Comment: There are better people in community those are more focused in solving problem instead of reading policies/help center of website. They does this because it is the sole purpose of website and not imposing policies.I hope next time if you have answer, you will first post it and then direct that person to help center page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **10k user** in JMeter **Thread Group** will be the limiting factor here. Using **single JMeter instance** you cannot afford to generate 10k users.Your machine running JMeter will be the **Bottleneck** here.Try using Distributed Load test.

[Distributed Load Test Step by Step](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Ramp-up time != think time, JMeter starts all threads during defined ramp-up period. Given 10k users and 2 seconds ramp-up time JMeter will start with 1 user, during 1st second 5k threads will start and during 2nd second remaining 5k will be kicked off.

Take a look at the following test elements:

- [Constant Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) - to simulate think time
- [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) - if you need all 10k threads to fire at exactly the same time.

Also your machine specifications might be too low to handle 10k simultaneous virtual users, if your host gets overloaded you may have to consider [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: Ok Dmitri, let me go through this pdf. Could you please answer second question of this post i.e. "Which all components are matter of concern and how to put them infront of DEV to fix them as bug or improvement?" Which report or listener I should use.??